# How to remove an :after effect for a specific id when a class applies the effect

Tags: html, css, list

You will see in my snippet below that I am trying to turn "Get a Quote" to more of a button style. Anytime I add padding to this element `navInverse`, it causes run off for the background color to the next line. I am also trying to get the `:after` effect to not take place with the `navInverse` object.The after effect currently puts a red line under the button.

If I add the following code to `navInverse`, it looks like the image below. This is how I want the button padding to appear, minus the overlapping part that gets pushed to the bottom.

Also, I cannot figure out why the `navInverse` color will not show as white. I have it coded as

```
color:#FFF;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px 12px;
```

[image]

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4sruks2/2/)

```css
nav {
 background: #FFF;
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px #E5E5E5;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#nav-logo {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 5%;
}
#nav-logo img {
 height: 80%;
 width: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#nav-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 17px;
}
#nav-list li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
#nav-list li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav-list li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 /*color: #4b4b4b;*/
 color: #747678;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:after {
 content: '';
    display: block;
 width: 0;
 margin-top: 6px;
 background: #BE1E2D;
 height: 2px;
 transition: width .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:hover {
 color: #4b4b4b;
 transition: all .3s;-webkit-transition: all .3s;
}
#nav-list li a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}
#navInverse {
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 color: #FFF;
 background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #BE1E2D, #981824);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#navInverse:after {
 content: '';
    display: none;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 transition: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <div id="nav-logo">
  <a href="/"><img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/logoBR.png" alt="MB Kit Systems"></a>
 </div>
 <div id="mobile-button"><img src="" class="hidden" alt=""></div>
 <div id="nav-pop">
 <div id="nav-pop-close"></div>
  <ul id="nav-list">
   <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="services.php">SERVICES</a></li>
   <li><a href="services">DESIGN</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.php" id="navInverse">GET A QUOTE</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the selector specificity, the regular selector (`#nav-list li a`) as a specificity of 3, but the override selector (`#navInverse`) has 1, so it get overridden.

One way to increase your selector specificity is make it `#nav-list li a#navInverse`.

I'm not sure that this is the result you wanted, but this is works.

```css
nav {
  background: #FFF;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #E5E5E5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#nav-logo img {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#nav-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 17px;
}

#nav-list li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#nav-list li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#nav-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  /*color: #4b4b4b;*/
  color: #747678;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}

#nav-list li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: #BE1E2D;
  height: 2px;
  transition: width .3s;
}

#nav-list li a:hover {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
}

#nav-list li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

#nav-list li a#navInverse {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #FFF;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #BE1E2D, #981824);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#navInverse:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav-logo">
    <a href="/"><img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/logoBR.png" alt="MB Kit Systems"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="mobile-button"><img src="" class="hidden" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav-pop">
    <div id="nav-pop-close"></div>
    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.php">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="services">DESIGN</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php" id="navInverse">GET A QUOTE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```